# Create bundle without default controller and route

Tags: symfony

Is this possible to create bundle without default controller and route?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it is. Only required file in the bundle is the bundle class.

Read more in the official documentation: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/page_creation.html#the-bundle-system

Comment: Just an example for this answer: https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataBluePrintBundle

Comment: @drupality the command will generate controllers and configuration. All you need to do is to remove them.